# Invalid comparison error python while scanning for outliers

Tags: python, pandas, outliers

I'm trying to extract the outliers from a pandas dataframe. I wanted to extract those by interquantile distance, but It triggered "TypeError: Invalid comparison between dtype=float64 and str", yet I don't see where it is a string or a float, when I checked both things I was comparing, upp_iqr, low_iqr where pandas.core.series.Series and prices list was a pandas.core.frame.DataFrame. The dataframe have only numbers in their cells. This is my code:

```
    prices_list = df.filter(regex='Price')
    q1 = prices_list.quantile(0.25)
    q3 = prices_list.quantile(0.75)
    iqr = q3 - q1
    low_iqr = q1 - (1.5 * iqr)
    upp_iqr = q3 + (1.5 * iqr)
    if any(x > low_iqr for x in prices_list):
        print("check_outlier: False")
        logging.debug(print(price_outliers))
    else:
        print("check_outlier: False")
        logging.debug(print(price_outliers))
```

I expected it to return a dataframe with their values and positions. Any help would be apreciated, please and thank you

Comment: What is `prices_list.dtypes` ?

Comment: It is a pandas.core.frame.DataFrame. Everything is either a dataframe or a series

Comment: ButI ask for `print (prices_list.dtypes)` not for  `print (type(prices_list))`

Comment: It says upp\low_iqr is a float64 and that prices_list has no attribute type.  Sorry, didnt know baout this one, thanks